What was the intention behind The Outreach Department?
I see that until recently, there used to be a room called The Outreach Department. It was created in April 2022.
It was frozen quite recently, in November 2024. (Actually, this room was frozen and unfrozen a few times in the past.)
Is the intention behind this room simply to gather HNQs? (The room topic simply says: "The Outreach Department: … where a feed of hot network questions gets posted so we can edit, close, and flag them (as appropriate)".) Or is this room for other things, as well? (The site already has one general-purpose room.)
If the room is worth keeping alive, perhaps one of the moderators could unfreeze it? The room was unfrozen again.

I don't know that there's a better answer to be had than the initial announcement: New chat room for the HNQ list

To answer the last subquestion: Nothing stops you from starting discussions there, if they are about (community) moderating HNQs.

@Wrzlprmft Could perhaps the tag ([meta-tag:chat]) be added to the duplicate target. (I actually checked this tag to see whether there was a previous discussion related to this room.) Thanks!

@Martin: Done …
